# How to interpret model results for Yes/No dependent variable

Tags: binary-data, glmm, interpretation

I have run a model for a data set that looks like the following:

```
site      date species         id success_rfid length success_seed seed_num
1  YB2 2/16/2019    BCCH 0110174217            0      2            1        1
2  YB2 2/16/2019    BCCH 0110174857            1      3            1        1
3  YB2 2/16/2019    BCCH 0110174217            0      1            1        1
4  YB2 2/16/2019    BCCH 0110174857            0      2            1        1
5  YB2 2/16/2019    WBNU 0110171AA5            0      2            1        1
6  YB2 2/22/2019    WBNU 0110171AA5            1      4            1        1
```

```
mod3 <- glmer(success_rfid ~ species + site + length + (1|id), family = binomial( link = "logit"), data = data)
```

This the output:

```
Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)   
(Intercept) -1.55910    0.59693  -2.612  0.00901 **
speciesTUTI  1.37388    0.66570   2.064  0.03903 * 
speciesWBNU  1.16029    0.76006   1.527  0.12687   
siteL3      -0.98732    0.63769  -1.548  0.12156   
siteYB2     -0.01193    0.74703  -0.016  0.98726   
length       0.25954    0.11648   2.228  0.02587 *
```

How do I go about interpreting what the output? I've done this for count data, but not binary data (Yes/No).

Answer (score 2):

The fixed-effects coefficients have the interpretation of log odds ratios (and log odds for the intercept). For example, the interpretation for the coefficient of `speciesTUTI` is the log odds ratio for the level `TUTI` versus the reference level for the factor variable `species`.

However, note that the inclusion of the random intercepts terms complicates to a degree this interpretation. Namely, these log odds ratios are conditional on the random effects. For more on this, check this [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/365907/interpretation-of-fixed-effects-from-mixed-effect-logistic-regression).